# Path of catkin workspace appears in install space

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**UPDATE** 201803100806 I can provide a reproduce sample.

Workspace path is mixed in `install` space. This makes me worry that I might have done something wrong, but I'm not quite sure.

- Q1. Is this supposed to be so?
- Q2. If the built package distributed to another computer that doesn't have the same path, would it still work?

**Issue**

In install space I see many mentions of the absolute path of catkin workspace as some of them citead below. I do NOT though see the catkin ws path in `setup.*sh`, and also when I ran `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` I do not see the catkin ws path in any environment variables.

Commands to reproduce:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/299cd69013e01c354edce2a1f903fffb

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285009/path-of-catkin-workspace-appears-in-install-space/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9388 on 2018-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I may have missed it, but what is your question exactly? Many of the occurences that you show are in `if (..) .. else ..` constructs, and the workspace path is not supposed to be used then, as those `if` statements check for which space they are actually in.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0